# Color the nodes according to certain values

Tags: graphs-and-networks, color

I have a simple graph, consisting 6 nodes and the connection is:

```
node = {{1, 2}, {2, 3}, {2, 4}, {4, 5}, {5, 6}, {3, 6}};
```

Each node corresponds to a weight, assuming it is

```
weight={1,2,3,4,5,6}
```

Now I want to plot this graph, showing the actual number on each node and assign the node color based on the weight. (If possible, I also would like to assign the color of the connection line with colors, changing smoothly from one node to another).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here is a quick example of coloring both vertices and edges with specified colors, along with the additional stipulation that an edge's color should transition between the colors of its associated vertices:

```
edges = {{1, 2}, {2, 3}, {2, 4}, {4, 5}, {5, 6}, {3, 6}};
weight = Range[6];
cols = ColorData[61] /@ weight;

Graph[UndirectedEdge @@@ edges, 
      EdgeShapeFunction -> ({AbsoluteThickness[4],
                             Line[#1, VertexColors -> cols[[List @@ #2]]]} &), 
      VertexSize -> Medium, VertexStyle -> Thread[Range[6] -> cols]]
```

[image: colored graph]

Comment: This is great. One more question, is it possible to label the circle with their number and also add a color bar on the right side of the figure?

Comment: ...shouldn't you have included those in the question in the first place? :| Anyway, look up `VertexLabels` and `PointLegend[]`.

Comment: :-) thanks. This is really helpful!

Comment: Sorry to bother you again but I cannot figure out how to use PoingLegrnd[]

Comment: Try `Legended[(* stuff *), PointLegend[cols, weight]]`.

Comment: I tried the following expression but it does not work.   Legended[{"P1", "P2", "P3", "P4", "P5", "P6"},   PointLegend[cols, N[weight]]]

Comment: If you had looked up the syntax of `Legended[]` and `PointLegend[]`, you would see that the first argument of `Legended[]` should be your graphic. As for `PointLegend[]`, the arguments are the colors and the labels. This is all in the docs.

Comment: Thanks for the tips. Now it works.

Answer (score 4):

You can use  rules to specify colors and `VertexStyle` to color the nodes, e.g.

```
col = Range[6] /. {1 -> Red, 2 -> Green, 3 -> Blue, 4 -> Purple, 
    5 -> Orange, 6 -> White};
Legended[Graph[UndirectedEdge @@@ node, 
  VertexStyle -> Thread[Range[6] -> col], VertexSize -> 0.2], 
 PointLegend[col, Range[6], 
  LegendMarkers -> Graphics[{EdgeForm[Black], Disk[]}], 
  LegendMarkerSize -> 20]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

There is [a package](https://github.com/szhorvat/IGraphM/releases) to make your life easer

```
<< IGraphM`
node = {{1, 2}, {2, 3}, {2, 4}, {4, 5}, {5, 6}, {3, 6}};
weight = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6};
IGVertexMap[ColorData[97], VertexStyle -> IGVertexProp[VertexWeight], 
 Graph[UndirectedEdge @@@ node, VertexWeight -> weight]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

If the weight which are used for colouring are not integers, it is useful to `Rescale` them:

```
IGVertexMap[ColorData["MintColors"], VertexStyle -> Rescale@*IGVertexProp[VertexWeight], 
 Graph[UndirectedEdge @@@ node, VertexWeight -> weight]]
```