# Coloring a graph using the new built-in commands

Tags: graphs-and-networks, color

In version 9 and before, when the `` Combinatorica` `` package was still usable, the commands `VertexColoring[g]` and `EdgeColoring[g]` used Brelaz's heuristic to find a (not necessarily optimal) vertex/edge coloring of the graph object `g`.

Is there a way this can be achieved using the new commands, without manually playing with the `VertexStyle`/`EdgeStyle` parameters? To be clear, I'm interested in producing visual output, so I'm currently doing this:

```
Graph[PetersenGraph[],
  GraphStyle -> "BasicBlack",
  BaseStyle -> EdgeForm[{Thick, Black}],
  VertexSize -> 0.25,
  EdgeStyle -> Thick,
  VertexStyle -> {1 -> Red, 2 -> Red, 3 -> Green, 4 -> Green, 5 -> Blue, 6 -> Blue,
                  7 -> Green, 8 -> Red, 9 -> Blue, 10 -> Red}]
```

to obtain the following output:

[image: colored graph]

Is there any way this can be done automatically? Also, why are the edges not 100% opaque? Adding `EdgeStyle-> {Thick, Opacity[1]}` made no difference to the output.

Comment: [Hope to help](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/154660/21532).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

With very minimal adjustment of the original *Combinatorica* code, here is an implementation of Brelaz coloring:

```
brelaz[g_?GraphQ] := 
     Module[{m = 0, v = VertexCount[g], cd, color, p, nc, e},
       cd = color = ConstantArray[0, v];
       While[m >= 0,
             p = Position[cd, m][[1, 1]]; 
             e = AdjacencyList[g, p];
             nc = Append[color[[e]], 0];
             color[[p]] = Min[Complement[Range[Max[nc] + 1], nc]];
             cd[[p]] = -2 v; 
             Scan[(cd[[#]]++) &, e]; 
             m = Max[cd]
       ];
       color
     ]
```

Test:

```
col = brelaz[PetersenGraph[5, 2]]
   {1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 2, 3, 1, 3, 1}

PetersenGraph[5, 2, EdgeStyle -> Gray, 
              VertexStyle -> MapIndexed[First[#2] -> ColorData[61, #1] &, col], 
              VertexSize -> Small]
```

[image: Brelaz-colored Petersen graph]

Compare with version 5.2:

```
<<DiscreteMath`Combinatorica`

VertexColoring[PetersenGraph, Algorithm -> Brelaz]
   {1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 2, 3, 1, 3, 1}
```

---

For completeness, here is the corresponding adapted edge coloring algorithm:

```
edgeColoring[g_?GraphQ] := Module[{c = brelaz[LineGraph[g]], e, se},
    e = Map[Sort, List @@@ EdgeList[g]];
    se = Sort[MapIndexed[Prepend[#2, #1] &, e]];
    Map[Last, Sort[Reverse[MapThread[Prepend, {se, c}], 2]]]]
```

Comment: Thank you! Any idea why the edges are slightly transparent in my example?

Comment: Specify a color with an explicit alpha channel of 1, e.g. `GrayLevel[1/2, 1]`.

Comment: It's better to use `_?GraphQ` than `_Graph`.  For example, `Graph[1]` is not a graph.  You seem to be assuming that the names of the vertices are the same as their indices. This is not the case in general, even when the names are integers up to `VertexCount[g]` (the ordering may be different).  But you can construct a graph which satisfies your assumption using `IndexGraph`.

Comment: This agrees with Combinatorica (and the plain English description in the Combinatorica book), but it is somewhat different from what Brélaz originally described (I just looked it up).  In the Combinatorica version, the "colour degree" of a vertex is the number of already coloured neighbours.  In the original Brélaz version, the "colour degree" is the number of adjacent colours. That may be smaller than the number of coloured neighbours when  multiple neighbours have the same colour. It's quite a bit more trouble to implement the original version.

Answer (score 9):

[IGraph/M 0.3.93](http://szhorvat.net/mathematica/IGraphM) and later include the same colouring algorithm as Combinatorica.

```
Needs["IGraphM`"]

IGVertexMap[
 ColorData[97],
 VertexStyle -> IGVertexColoring,
 PetersenGraph[VertexSize -> Large, GraphStyle -> "BasicBlack"]
]
```

[image]

Note that while Combinatorica claims to implement Brélaz's heuristic, the algorithm is not the same [described by Brélaz here](http://www.ic.unicamp.br/~rberga/papers/p251-brelaz.pdf).  Combinatorica chooses vertices based on the number of already coloured neighbours.  Brélaz suggests choosing based on the distinct neighbouring colours ("saturation degree").

In IGraph/M 0.3.98 and later you can also use `IGMinimumVertexColoring` to obtain an optimal colouring.